# Can't Call activity function from adapter

Tags: java, android

I would like to call activity function from Adapter. I am trying something like this:

```
 ((MainActivity)mCtx).SampleVoid();
```

But i've got the error: **java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to**

```
public void SampleVoid(){

    Toast.makeText(this,"Testowa metoda",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the activity through the Adapter constructor.
Generally you do this through interfaces

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MAdapter.Listener {

    private MAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdapter = new MAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) { }

}
```

Then

```
public class MAdapter {

    private Listener listener;

    MAdapter(Listener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    interface Listener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is happening because you are trying to cast the Application context to the Activity context. First of all, I wouldn't recommend you sending and storing context inside the adapter. I would recommend you to create an interface for communication back to the Activity at specific action from the adapter. For example:

**Activity code:**

```
SomeAdapter adapter = new SomeAdapter();
    adapter.setOnAdapterActionListener(new OnAdapterActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSomeAdapterAction() {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Testowa metoda",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**Adapter code:**

```
public class SomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { // extend from the same adapter that you are extending now.
    private OnAdapterActionListener onAdapterActionListener;

    public SomeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(onAdapterActionListener != null) {
                    onAdapterActionListener.onSomeAdapterAction();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void setOnAdapterActionListener(OnAdapterActionListener onAdapterActionListener) {
        this.onAdapterActionListener = onAdapterActionListener;
    }
}

interface OnAdapterActionListener {
    void onSomeAdapterAction();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know passing context to an adapter is a common practice. What are the reasons you don't recommend it?

Comment: I would avoid it passing context to Adapter and any other classes that by default doesn't include the context in it. Of course, if it's possible. With passed context to some class, we expose that class for a possible memory leak if we don't handle the situation with caution. Maybe for an Adapter, this is not such a big issue, but if you can do it without a context inside of an adapter, then I highly recommend do it like this. There is probably a good reason why the Google team didn't provide context inside of the adapter by default.

Comment: Also, if you have viewHolder instance available wherever you need context, you can get one from its view component like this: `viewHolder.itemView.getContext()`

Comment: When context is passed as parameter, the original context is copied/replicated in memory? Do `viewHolder.itemView.getContext()` call the original context instead of making a copy?

Comment: I recommend you reading this blog post how does Java pass parameters in methods: https://www.javaworld.com/article/3512039/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html 
With this blog post, you will get a better understanding of this. Passed context creates a copy with a pointer to the original instance. 

`viewHolder.itemView.getContext()` use context that is available inside of view holder root view. With this approach, you just use this context and then you don't need to deal with it anymore.